# Automating ETL Data pipeline in snowflake using streams and tasks

Tags: stream, pipe, task, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, etl

I am trying to automate a ETL data pipeline process where the aim is to load JSON from s3 into **staging table** and once data is loaded into staging table a task extracts data from the json and loads it into a **extraction table** and finally a stored procedure loads data into **dimension tables** from the extraction table.

I created a snowpipe which is able to load json successfully into the **staging table** from s3, but I am stuck on a point where I was trying to load data automatically into **extraction table** from **staging table** using stream (**stream** is created on top of **staging table**). My understanding is stream can have track on changes happening in the staging table and any new file that is coming into the staging area only has to be executed and loaded into extraction table.

Could someone please help me with the **create task syntax combining streams** based on new insert that has happened in the staging table please

The code I am using is below and it doesn't load data into the extraction table at all.

```
create or replace task insertintoextractiontable

    WAREHOUSE = Default_WH    

WHEN
  SYSTEM$STREAM_HAS_DATA('STAGESTREAM')
```

Comment: After creating the task, did you execute the RESUME command? By default, new tasks are SUSPENDED.

Comment: Hi Michael Golos, I tried to resume the task but it throws the error Task should have a SCHEDULE or AFTER to be resumed.

Comment: Should I include something like SCHEDULE = '5 minute' to my create task statement above in mypost

Comment: Yes, you have to set SCHEDULE or AFTER another job to run this job.

Answer (score 0):

I would check below points to check functioning of tasks

1. Check Status tasks and if  they are new , they will be in suspension status and need to resume.
2. Query below to see  what happened to history of task

   > select *
   > from table(information_schema.task_history(
   > scheduled_time_range_start=>dateadd('hour',-1,current_timestamp()),
   > result_limit => 10,
   > task_name=>'MYTASK'))
3. Check config of cron syntax while creating task if above points doesn’t work.

Comment: Hi Anand, I tried to resume the task but it throws the error Task should have a SCHEDULE or AFTER to be resumed.

Comment: I tried to resume the task but it throws the error Task should have a SCHEDULE or AFTER to be resumed. Should I include something like SCHEDULE = '5 minute' to my create task statement above in mypost

Comment: Yes add a schedule to  task ..

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that if You create a Child Task pointing to a Mother Task with the AFTER clause and the Mother Task has never been resumed (at least once), the Snow will retrieve the "Task should have a SCHEDULE or AFTER to be resumed." error when You try to resume It, even if You resume and suspend the Mother Task and try again, It seems like a bug.

So make sure the Mother Task to be pointed at with the AFTER clause has already been resumed at least once BEFORE You create the Child Task.